# androidx.navigation library update to 2.2.2 version Release build issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have issue with androidx.navigation last updates

I have noticed that after fresh update **(2.2.2)** crashed if build is **RELEASE**
with error like

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in 
com.somedomain.android:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #12 in 
com.somedomain.android:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView


Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in 
com.somedomain.android:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$e: Unable to instantiate fragment 
androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment: make sure class name exists
```

I am using:

```
ext.versions = [
   ...
   nav_version        : '2.2.2',
]

ext.libs = [
   ...
   nav_fragment       : "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$versions.nav_version",
   nav_ui             : "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$versions.nav_version",
]
```

In App gradle

```
 ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "false"]
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable = true
        }
       
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "true"]
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable = false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    ...
implementation libs.nav_fragment
implementation libs.nav_ui
```

Navigation host in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_host"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />
    
    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

Language: Kotlin

Has anybody face with the problem like this?

Note: With version 2.2.1 everything was OK.
Debug version build also is OK

I think the issue related to this change.
according to official Android nav components [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)

The navigation-common-ktx ProGuard rules now correctly only keep the NavArgs classes that are used rather than all NavArgs instances. This was previously released in Navigation 2.3.0-alpha03. (b/150213558

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Damn. I found.

It's need to add `-keep class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment`

in the **proguard-rules.pro** file.